# Deployment pipeline with Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have been trying to do cicd with jenkin pipeline.
I have pull project from git, create jar and run the jar file
Jar file starts the server

and after the server starts the next stage doesn't gets executed
next step is to run karate test cases.

Got stuck here.

This is my pipeline script::

```
node {
    def mavenHome = tool name: "Maven", type: "maven"
    stage('git clone') {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'b6423164-b18d-43e0-a48f-edd10f90396d', url: 'https://github.com/prajdshakya93/Employee-Record-Managment-System.git']]])
    }
    stage('build artifact with dependencies'){
        bat "${mavenHome}/bin/mvn clean compile assembly:single"
        bat("xcopy config.properties C:\\ProgramData\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\ermsPipelinePratice\\target")
    }
    stage('run jar file'){
        dir("target") {
            bat "java -jar erms-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
        }
    }
    stage('run karate'){
        bat "${mavenHome}/bin/mvn test -Dtest=KarateTests"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some logs and a little explanation about what this jar file do. As a hunch, I think you're running a jar file that starts working and will never exit and because of that, you will stuck in this stage until you reach the Jenkins global timeout.

Comment: yes that is whats happening...jar file starts a server. and after that process gets stuck. is there any other way of doing this. i am new in jenkins

Comment: I don't see this as a matter of the tool that you're using. You shouldn't start a service inside your pipeline, unless there is an exit scenario at the end.